# Composer удаляет мои файлы

Tags: symfony2, composer, repository, silex

Есть проект на `Silex` который достался мне от одного разработчика, я его дорабатываю и понадобилось прикрутить языковую локализацию, имею такую структуру папки `vendor`

> [image]

<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/l2ZvQ0Vt5Oxb2J.png))</sub>
 загружаю репозиторий `composer require symfony/translation`, в итоге получаю следующее:

```
composer require symfony/translation
Using version ^3.2 for symfony/translation
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing emberlabs/gravatarlib (dev-master)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (3.7.x-dev)
  - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (1.2.x-dev)
  - Removing phpunit/php-token-stream (dev-master)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (1.2.x-dev)
  - Removing doctrine/dbal (dev-master)
  - Removing doctrine/common (2.4.x-dev)
  - Removing doctrine/inflector (dev-master)
  - Removing doctrine/cache (dev-master)
  - Removing doctrine/collections (dev-master)
  - Removing doctrine/annotations (dev-master)
  - Removing doctrine/lexer (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/validator (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/serializer (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/process (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/monolog-bridge (dev-master)
  - Removing monolog/monolog (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/finder (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/css-selector (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/browser-kit (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/form (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/options-resolver (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/property-access (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/locale (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/intl (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/icu (1.0.x-dev)
  - Removing symfony/security (dev-master)
  - Removing symfony/filesystem (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.0.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/config (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/config (v2.8.14)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/yaml (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.8.14)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/translation (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/translation (v3.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (dev-master)
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/stopwatch (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/stopwatch (v2.8.14)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/twig-bridge (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/twig-bridge (v2.8.14)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/routing (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/routing (v3.0.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/http-foundation (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.0.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.0.9)
    Loading from cache     

  - Removing symfony/debug (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/http-kernel (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.0.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (dev-master)
  - Installing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v2.8.14)
    Loading from cache

  - Updating pimple/pimple (1.1.x-dev bc2fc12 => v1.1.1)
    Checking out 2019c145fe393923f3441b23f29bbdfaa5c58c4d

  - Installing silex/silex (v1.3.5)
    Loading from cache

Package kilte/silex-captcha is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use amstaffix/silex-captcha instead.
Generating autoload files
```

При открытии приложения естественно получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener does not exist' in \vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider.php:78 Stack trace: #0 \vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider.php(78): ReflectionMethod->__construct('Symfony\\Compone...', '__construct') #1 \vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Application.php(178): Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider->register(Object(Silex\Application)) #2 \src\app.php(138): Silex\Application->register(Object(Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider), Array) #3 \site.ru\index.php(12): require('C:\\OpenServer\\g...') #4 {main} thrown in \vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider.php on line 78
```

Нашел несколько решений этой проблемы

1. Использовать `--prefer-dist` - не помогло.
2. Добавить `vendor` в `.gitignore` - результат тот же.
3. Удалить все `.git` из директории - безрезультатно.

Comment: я бы с удовольстввием посмотрел на composer.json + composer.lock, скорее всего вы как-то неправильно используете composer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно данные пакеты были удалены из файла `composer.json`, но при этом присутствуют в файле `./vendor/composer/installed.json`. Последний используется для хранения перечня установленных пакетов.

Сравнив эти 2 файла композер определит какие пакеты были удалены из composer.json "вручную" и удалит их из папки vendor.

Удалите из файла `installed.json` записи относящиеся к пакетам, которые хотите сохранить.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, думал что проблему вообще не решить!